# casting a string to OdbcType enum

Tags: c#, string, casting, enums

I need to create instances of OdbcParameter at runtime using values ​​returned from the database as attributes. 
My problem is that the description of the data type is returned as a string in uppercase, which is why Enum.Parse or Enum.TryParse fails to cast my string to it's enum's correspondig value:

```
var datatype = (OdbcType)Enum.Parse(typeof(OdbcType), "NVARCHAR");
```

To solve this issue I have created a Dictionary:

```
public static Dictionary<string, OdbcType> OdbcDataTypeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, OdbcType>()
        {
            {"BIGINT", OdbcType.BigInt},
            {"BINARY", OdbcType.Binary},
            {"BIT", OdbcType.Bit},
            {"CHAR", OdbcType.Char},
            {"DATE", OdbcType.Date},
            {"DATETIME", OdbcType.DateTime},
            {"DECIMAL", OdbcType.Decimal},
            {"DOUBLE", OdbcType.Double},
            {"IMAGE", OdbcType.Image},
            {"INT", OdbcType.Int},
            {"NCHAR", OdbcType.NChar},
            {"NTEXT", OdbcType.NText},
            {"NUMERIC", OdbcType.Numeric},
            {"NVARCHAR", OdbcType.NVarChar},
            {"REAL", OdbcType.Real},
            {"SMALLDATETIME", OdbcType.SmallDateTime},
            {"SMALLINT", OdbcType.SmallInt},
            {"TEXT", OdbcType.Text},
            {"TIME", OdbcType.Time},
            {"TIMESTAMP", OdbcType.Timestamp},
            {"TINYINT", OdbcType.TinyInt},
            {"UNIQUEIDENTIFIER", OdbcType.UniqueIdentifier},
            {"VARBINARY", OdbcType.VarBinary},
            {"VARCHAR", OdbcType.VarChar}
        };
```

It's working, but I'm not convinced that is the best solution.

Does anybody have any ideas on better ways to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enum.TryParse has another boolean parameter to ignore the case, that will work [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You want the overloaded constructor of [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which has an `ignoreCase` parameter i.e.

```
(OdbcType)Enum.Parse(typeof(OdbcType), "NVARCHAR", true);
```